# How to create html table from multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, html-table

I am sending a HTTP request to a Server and get a response with json format. I convert it to array using:

```
$response = file_get_contents($final_url);
$responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
```

Here is server response array(`$responseArray`).

```
Array ( 
[status] => OK 
[result] => Array (
      [0] => Array
           (
             [trainno] => 12151
             [name] => SAMARSATA EXP
             [cls] => 1A 2A 3A SL
             [rundays] => F,Sa
             [from] => BQA
             [fromname] => Bankura
             [dep] => 03.45
             [to] => HWH
             [toname] => Howrah Jn
             [arr] => 08.25
             [pantry] => 0
             [type] => SUPERFAST
             [datefrom] => 10-Apr-2015
             [dateto] => 12-Apr-2020
             [traveltime] => 04.40
           )
      [1] => Array
           (
             [trainno] => 12151
             [name] => SAMARSATA EXP
             [cls] => 1A 2A 3A SL
             [rundays] => F,Sa
             [from] => BQA
             [fromname] => Bankura
             [dep] => 03.45
             [to] => HWH
             [toname] => Howrah Jn
             [arr] => 08.25
             [pantry] => 0
             [type] => SUPERFAST
             [datefrom] => 10-Apr-2015
             [dateto] => 12-Apr-2020
             [traveltime] => 04.40
           )
    )
)
```

Now I want to print 'result' array in html table format if [status] =>OK. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an if condition, if it satisfies, then iterate the said array, pointing to proper indices:

```
if($responseArray['status'] === 'OK') {
    foreach($responseArray['result'] as $result) {
        echo $result['name']; // and other indices
    }
}
```

Printing it into a table markup is just a creating a normal table which includes the markup.

Super rough example:

```
<?php if($responseArray['status'] === 'OK'): ?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($headers as $h): ?>
            <th><?php echo $h; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($responseArray['result'] as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($row as $value); ?>
                <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hello Ghost. help me 1 more

Comment: Array ([status] => OK [result] => Array ( [pnr] => 4106121143 [cls] => 3A [eticket] => 1 [journey] => 09-Apr-2015 [trainno] => 12740 [name] => VSKP 

GARIB RATH [from] => SC [to] => VSKP [brdg] => SC [passengers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [bookingstatus] => G14 52GN [currentstatus] => Can/Mod 

[coach] => ) [1] => Array ( [bookingstatus] => G14 54GN [currentstatus] => Can/Mod [coach] => ) ) [chart] => CHART PREPARED [error] => ) )

Comment: @BikashMahata when another level on an array is introduced, just add another foreach inside of it, it will work just the same `foreach($row['passengers'] as $val){ echo $val['bookingstatus']; }`

Comment: I have added : if($responseArray['status'] === 'OK') {
  foreach($responseArray['result'] as $result) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$result['journey'].'</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
  }
 }

Comment: but it print first character of each

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'journey' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\railway\backEnd\jsonProcess.php</b> on line <b>71</b><br />

Comment: @BikashMahata no need for foreach, its just `echo $responseArray['result']['journey'];`

Comment: problem faced in another lavel

Comment: I want to print another level of array value i.e $responseArray['passengers'] in another table.

Comment: @BikashMahata the comment thread is getting too long, anyway `foreach($responseArray['result']['passengers'] as $val){ echo $val['bookingstatus']; }` anyway if you have other question, you should post it on another separate thread instead

Comment: oh I got it . foreach($responseArray['result']['passengers'] as $passengers)